# Generating a simple bar chart with d3.js and an array of form data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array of form data like this: `['Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Prefer Not To Say']` and a variety of other arrays with other form data. I'd like to create a general purpose simple bar chart generator with D3.js that gives the percentages, or even just a count, of each item in the array.

Here's my code so far, but I only gets bars, without labels. I lose them when I use Object.values(). How do I change my code, so I can add the labels in the bar charts?

```
function pieChart (array) {
  var pieces = {}
  array.forEach( function (element) {
    return pieces[element] ? pieces[element] += 1 : pieces[element] = 1
  })
  console.log(pieces)

  var section = d3.create("section")
      section.style("margin", "50px 0")
      section.style("font", "10px sans-serf")
      section.style("text-align", "left")
      section.style("color", "black")

  var bars = section.selectAll("div")

  var barUpdate = bars.data(Object.values(pieces))

  var barNew = barUpdate.join("div")
      barNew.style("background", "steelblue")
      barNew.style("padding", "3px 10px")
      barNew.style("margin", "2px")
      barNew.style("color", "white")
      barNew.style("border-top-right-radius", "10px")
      barNew.style("border-bottom-right-radius", "10px")
      //barNew.style("position", "relative")
      //barNew.style("left","50px")

  var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,d3.max(Object.values(pieces))]).range([0,100])

  barNew.style("width", d => `${x(d)}%`)
  // barNew.style("width", d => `${d * 10}px`)

  barNew.text(d => d)

  var charts = document.getElementById('charts')
  charts.append(section.node())
}
```

Comment: Solved it by transforming my object into an array or arrays using Object.keys and a array.map : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd propose a better data structure: an array of objects in which each object has defined property names (for instance, `type` and `value`), specially given the solution you proposed in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262620/generating-a-simple-bar-chart-with-d3-js-and-an-array-of-form-data/61262927#comment108377902_61262620). An array of objects with defined properties is not only clearer (for other programmers), but also easier to change and more versatile.

Here is a simple demo using `Array.prototype.reduce`, purposefully verbose:

```js
const dataArray = ['Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Prefer Not To Say'];

const data = dataArray.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  const foundObject = acc.find(function(d) {
    return d.type === curr;
  });
  if (foundObject) {
    foundObject.value += 1;
  } else {
    acc.push({
      type: curr,
      value: 1
    })
  };
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(data)
```